# how can I get sum of duration in days which is having multiple rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having one table looks like below,

```
ID  |  duty |  startDate  |  Enddate


01  | yes  | 2011-10-15  | 2011-12-15

01  | yes  | 2012-01-10  |  2012-05-25

03  | yes  | 2012-02-23  | 2012-03-25

01  | no   | 2012-05-25  |2012-06-06

01  | yes  | 2012-07-10  | 2012-12-03

02  | yes  | 2012-08-21  | 2012-12-10
```

I need to get following results,

```
ID | duty | duration (in days)

01 | yes  | xxx

02 | yes  | yyy

03 | yes  | zzz

01 | no   | iii
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try something like follows:

```
SELECT ID, duty, SUM(DATEDIFF(dd, startDate, endDate)) as duration 
FROM [Table] 
GROUP BY ID, duty
```

DATEDIFF documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx

don't know if the `GROUP BY` is what you're expecting

Comment: additionally, what does it mean if the date ranges overlap?

Comment: Good question... The example looks like it would not happen, but in such a case I would go with stored procedures, since using a direct query could become a little bit tricky (if even possible)